# Something like the derivative, but invertible?

Tags: calculus

You can't do inverse derivatives, because derivatives aren't injective. However, I can construct something that's kind of like a derivative but is invertible. Let's say that instead of mapping from functions to functions, we will map from pairs of functions $(f(x),g(x))$ to pairs of functions. This operation, $D$, will be defined as,

$$
D (f(x),g(x)) = \left(\frac{d}{dx}f(x), f(0) + \int_0^x g(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right)
$$

Then, $D^{-1}$ would act as,
$$
D^{-1} (f(x),g(x)) = \left(g(0) + \int_0^x f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t, \frac{d}{dx} g(x) \right)
$$
Which means that if $P$ is an operator that flips tuples so that $P(f,g) = (g,f)$, then $PDP(f,g) = D^{-1}(f,g)$. This thing also has the interesting property that if you start with $(f,0)$ and start iterating $D$, the taylor series of $f$ about $0$ would appear in the second component of the tuple. Finally, it's similar to what is necessary to solve a differential equation: the left side of the tuple could be thought of as the differential equation itself, and the right side as the initial conditions.

Are there any "known ideas" that are similar to what I am grasping at here? It feels like this is evidence of an object more abstract than functions that serves as the "true home" of derivatives, but I don't know what that would be.

Comment: What if $f$ is undefind at $0$?

Comment: @David I guess you could pick whatever starting point you wanted, it doesn't have to be 0. I'm aware of that uncomfortable specificity, part of what I'm curious about is whether there is another way to do it that lacks that problem.

Comment: You could use some $a$ for which $g$ and $f$ are both defined.

Comment: $\displaystyle D(g,f)=\left(g'(x),g(0)+\int_0^xf(t)\,dt\right)\not=\left(g(0)+\int_0^xf(t)\,dx,g'(x)\right)=D^{-1}(f,g).$ You need an additional swap operation to get equality.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Good catch, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, that looks better!

Comment: I mean it kind of depends on what you want to do, but if you want to make derivative bijective, it feels easier to me to simply map it like this insteand: $f \mapsto (Df,f(0))$. The inverse would then be $(g,c)\mapsto c+ \int \limits_{0}^x g(t)dt $

Comment: Well, except that your $D^{-1}$ really isn't the inverse of $D$ anymore, is it? What happens if you compute $D(D^{-1}(f,g))?$